# Conflicting calls to viewDidLoad() and another block of code

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, viewdidload

[Screen in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vip2X.jpg) I am trying to call the `viewDidLoad()` func here with the `question()` func a set number of times and only then call the code for the new view controller to be pushed. But, the code for both is getting executed at the same exact time such that as soon as the first round finishes, the view controller is pushed. I have tried using loops in different variations, but those attempts all led to similar results. Ideas? And thanks in advance!

```swift
var num1 = Int()
var num2 = Int()
var userInput = 0
    
@IBAction func numbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
        answerLabel.text = answerLabel.text! + String(sender.tag - 1)
        userInput = Int(answerLabel.text!)!
        
        answer()
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Views configuration
        question()
    }

func answer() {
    let answer = num1 + num2
        
    if userInput == answer {
        answerLabel.text = ""
        viewDidLoad()
        let scoreVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ScoreViewController") as! ScoreViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scoreVC, animated: true)
    }
}


func question() {
        num1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
        num2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
        questionLabel.text = "\(num1)  +  \(num2)"
}
```

Comment: calling the `viewDidLoad` in a custom function seems weird. I'm pretty sure you should not do that. I also don't quit understand your Problem. Please show more code and describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Deitsch Hi! I did edit the question and also added a screenshot. Basically, every time the answer is correct, there should be a new question ready with the answer field blank. That is what necessitated the viewDidLoad() call inside of the custom func. Once the set number of questions (3, 5, 10, etc) have finished being answered, you should be directed to another view controller that displays the score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quit e few things that we can improve here. I'll start at basic.
As these numbers are unset at the beginning we don't have to assign them yet. So instead of settings them to a default value we can leave them as Optionals which allows us to just define the type and leave them be for an assignment later on.

```swift
var num1: Int?
var num2: Int?
```

Now we wanna show a Question. The thing is, the `viewDidLoad` shall only be used when - as the name suggests - the view loads. Because of this we simply create a Method and move our logic there. You already did that, I just renamed your function to a more speaking name

```swift
viewDidLoad() {
    showNewQuestion()
}

showNewQuestion() { // previously question()
    num1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    num2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    questionLabel.text = "\(num1)  +  \(num2)"
}
```

So far so good. Now we gotta check the input against the random value in the Button send function. Instead of force unwrapping (`!`) it is better practise to safely unwrap (`?`).

```swift
@IBAction func numbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let userInput = answerLabel.text, let userInputAsInt = Int(userInput) else { 
        return 
    }
    checkAnswer(userInput: userInputAsInt) // previously answere()
}
```

Lastly we improve your `answer()` function. The thing you left is to count how many questions have been answered. If we don't ever check that how should the program know when to show the score? To fix this problem we remember how many questions were asked (`correctAnsweres` ) and we define a threshold when to show the score (`showScoreAfter`)

```swift
var correctAnsweres = 0
var showScoreAfter = 5 

func checkAnswer(userInputAsInt: Int) {
    let answer = num1 + num2

    if userInputAsInt != answers { // early exit if answered wrong
        return
    }
    correctAnsweres += 1
    answerLabel.text = ""
    
    //either show score
    if correctAnsweres % ShowScoreAfter == 0 {
        let scoreVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ScoreViewController") as! ScoreViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scoreVC, animated: true)
    }
   // or new Question
    else {
        showNewQuestion()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're awesome.